# ES6 includes but case insensitive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know I can loop through array and just change value `toLowerCase()`.

I'm curious if there's a `reactjs` or `es6` method that can check if the value is in array.

On addTodo function. You can see that I use includes but this method is case sensitive.

Here's what I have

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="todo">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <p>{this.props.children}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.todos = [
            'Get Up from bed', 
            'Eat Breakfast'
        ];
    }

    eachTodo(task, i) {
        return (
            <Todo key={i} index={i}>{task}</Todo>
        )
    }

    addToDo() {
        let task_title = this.refs.newTodo.value;

        if(task_title !== '') {
            let arr = this.todos;

            var arr_tlc = this.todos.map((value) => {
                return value.toLowerCase();
            })

            if(arr_tlc.indexOf(task_title.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
                arr.push(task_title);

                this.setState({
                    todos: arr
                });
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-app">
                <input ref="newTodo" placeholder="Task"/>
                <button onClick={this.addToDo.bind(this)}>Add Todo</button>

                <div className="todos">
                    {this.todos.map(this.eachTodo)}
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }   
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the order in the array of importance?

Comment: @trincot No. I just need to check.

Comment: OK in that case I would suggest using a different data structure for your todo list. See my answer.

Comment: You're not using `includes`, you're using `indexOf`?

Comment: You can either use `this.todos.map(t => t.toLowerCase()).includes(tasktitle)` or `this.todos.some(t => t.toLowerCase() == tasktitle)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `Map` instead of an array for your todo list. A `Map` has the advantage that it provides key-based look-up in constant time, and does not store duplicate entries with the same key. You could then use the lower case variant as the key, and the original (mixed-case) string as the value for that key.

You could define `todos` as a `Map` instead of an array, and use the lower case string as the key:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.todos = new Map();
    this.addToDo('Get Up from bed'); 
    this.addToDo('Eat Breakfast');
}
```

Then, to add the task becomes very straightforward, as a `Map` overwrites duplicates:

```
addToDo() {
    this.todos.set(task_title.toLowerCase(), task_title);
    this.setState({
        todos: this.todos
    });
 }
```

In rendering you would need to use `Array.from(..., <map-function>)`, as `.map` is not defined for `Map` objects:

```
<div className="todos">
    {Array.from(this.todos, this.eachTodo)}
</div>
```

Which means the `eachToDo` method will receive a pair of strings (an array), instead of a string, and we want to display the second of the pair, so using index `[1]`:

```
eachTodo(task, i) {
    return (
        <Todo key={i} index={i}>{task[1]}</Todo>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your `.forEach` comment is incorrect, you are right is doesn't have `.map`, but `.forEach` will not work in this case since it will not return anything. Generally it's also a bad idea to store data in `this.todos`, it should all be in `this.state.todos`. You'd also be _much_ better off not mutating the Map, since mutating it and then calling `.setState` with the same value makes the code hard to follow. Maybe consider creating a new Map with the state `this.setState({todos: new Map([ ...this.state.todos, [task_title.toLowerCase(), task_title] ])});`

Comment: Indeed, the `forEach` was the wrong solution to get a map-like behaviour. Modified it to `Array.from`.

Comment: Good explanation of a map. I still don't quite understand the usage, but this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No, the only built-in methods are case sensitive. You'll need that loop and either `toLowerCase` or a case-insensitive regular expression (perhaps tucked away in a useful reusable function).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Which do you prefer, regex or (loop + toLowerCase)?

Comment: Seems es6 support Array extension to use 'find' method. So you can specify finder as aninym function with 'toLowerCase' inside

Comment: @VadimB: Right. Which is a loop.

Comment: @KevinDurant: With your use case, I'd probably do the `toLowerCase` thing because it's simple and not performance-critical. The flip side is if you have a handy regular expression escape function such as [this rejected proposal](https://github.com/benjamingr/RegExp.escape) (so you can turn user input into a regular expression without worrying about special chars), then turning the user input into a regex is also fairly simple. So...

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. I already did it using map first. I'm not sure if it's the proper way. Check my update.