# JS search for values in the array

Tags: javascript

I have array:

```
  list_keyword=["My","name,"JElly"];
```

Example 1:

```
  var check = list_keyword.includes('JElly');
  Result: True
```

Example 2:

```
  var param= list_keyword.includes('jelly');
  Result : False
```

How can I get the result True as Example 1 . Thanks

Comment: `var result = list_keyword.some(x => x.toLowerCase() === searchValue.toLowerCase())`

Comment: [You can't with `.includes()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543888/es6-includes-but-case-insensitive) without either changing the array items to be forced into a case (*and parameter*).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript contains case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993773/javascript-contains-case-insensitive)

Comment: If you want to dive into the wonderful world of [locales](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), `list_keyword.some(keyword => searchValue.localeCompare(keyword, 'en', {usage: 'search', sensitivity: 'accent'}) === 0)`

Comment: Thanks you verry much

Answer (score 0):

Simply make every string in the list lower-case, then check:

```
list_keyword.map(function(i){return i.toLowerCase()}).includes('jelly')
```

Comment: My bad! Understood wrong. But just a pointer, please look for dupes first

Comment: @ᴬᴶᵁᴾᴾᴬᴸ this is definitely a solution but do you think you 'd be better off saying `.includes('jelly'.toLowerCase())` too ? That is, wrap it in a function which takes a query string `query` and check `... .includes(query.toLowerCase())` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to search the string in array as below:

```js
var arr = ["My", "name", "JELLY"];

function searchString(strValue) {
  var arrToUp = String.prototype.toUpperCase.apply(arr).split(",");
  var arrToLow = String.prototype.toLowerCase.apply(arr).split(",");
  console.log((arrToUp.includes(strValue) || arrToLow.includes(strValue) || arr.includes(strValue)) ? 'true' : 'false')
}

searchString("jelly");
searchString("JELLY");
```